# What's the relation between a scope and a resource in OAuth2?

Tags: scope, oauth-2.0, resources

Going over the [OAuth2 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749), I couldn't figure out the relation between a **scope** and a **resource** :(

Looking at [Google's oauth2 scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes), is the term `scope` refer to the API the Client app wants to access and the user may grant access to?

If so, what is the resource? The actual data?

What if the user wants to allow access to only part of the data (resources)? For example, allowing client apps see only part of my google plus circles?

Am I in the right direction at all?